# In Case statement update date not greater than today date

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, case

Hi as per current statement i am updating the date in table as per below statement. I want to update the date that will be not more than today date. If the date will be more than today date then it will update with today date.

```
Update visiting 
set OriginArrvDate
       WHEN DATEPART(weekday,ORDDATE)=6 THEN DATEADD(dd,3,ORDDATE)
       WHEN DATEPART(weekday,ORDDATE)=7 THEN DATEADD(dd,3,ORDDATE)
       WHEN DATEPART(weekday,ORDDATE)=1 THEN DATEADD(dd,2,ORDDATE)
       WHEN DATEPART(weekday,ORDDATE)=2 THEN DATEADD(dd,1,ORDDATE)
       ELSE ORDDATE END
where 
orddate>=CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(dd,-100,getdate()))
```

In above script i am trying that when after calculating the date in  ( DATEADD(dd,3,ORDDATE) )   if output will be greater than today date then it will be update with today date.

***Example** : ORDATE is '2021-09-26' so as per current condition ORDDATE will be 2021-09-29 but i want the result after calculating the date not more than today date. So the date will be ' 2021-09-27'
If the ORDATE calculation  below today date then it will be fine and not change in date required.
Thanks for your reply*

**UPDATE : -**
As per suggestion i have add data with Script on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ef8d6) . If you review the data for visiting table for Oid 1 and 5 . Both updated data for OriginArrvDate is more than today date. I want to update the OriginArrvDate with today date when new ordDate is more than current date.

Comment: Thanks for the link i will read it in depth. But current i want to get the answer for above question.

Comment: I have added example as per your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a CTE which makes it very easy to test your logic by applying a `CASE` expression ([not a `CASE` statement](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression)) to the output of your *existing* `CASE` expression.

```
;WITH x AS
(
   SELECT Oid, ORDDATE, OriginArrvDate,
     CalcDate = CASE DATEPART(weekday, ORDDATE)
       WHEN 6 THEN DATEADD(DAY, 3, ORDDATE)
       WHEN 7 THEN DATEADD(DAY, 3, ORDDATE)
       WHEN 1 THEN DATEADD(DAY, 2, ORDDATE)
       WHEN 2 THEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, ORDDATE)
       ELSE ORDDATE END
   FROM dbo.visiting
   WHERE orddate >= CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY, -100, getdate()))  
   AND OriginArrvDate IS NULL
)
--SELECT *,
/* -- */ UPDATE x SET 
OriginArrvDate = CASE 
  WHEN CalcDate > GETDATE() THEN GETDATE() 
  ELSE CalcDate END
--FROM x;
```

Thanks for the fiddle, but I wrote a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c4c689d9ddebb290e9fc06d43b9a6248) here because I couldn't get SQLFiddle to properly show the update.

In addition to [using `DAY` instead of `dd`](https://sqlblog.org/dates#shorthand) I would also make sure to [always specify a table's schema](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).